# MySQL Install trouble Mac OSX 10.6.6

Tags: mysql, mac, installation, osx-snow-leopard

I have tried installing versions 5.5.11 and 5.1.56 of the MySQL Community Server DMG on my new MacBook Pro 2GHz Intel Core i7 running OS X 10.6.6.

It claims that installation is successful, and the Preference Pane window claims that the server is running, but I can't run 'mysql' commands in the Terminal, nor does any MySQL related process show in the Activity Monitor. Can anyone help?

I tried the answer given here, but still no action.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605659/mysql-wont-start-on-mac-osx

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

added these lines into your `~/.bash_profile`

If you don't have one, just do vim .bash_profile, hit 'i' to enter insert mode, paste in the lines, hit esc, and type `:w` (to save) then `:q` (to quit)

```
alias mysql='/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql'

alias mysqladmin='/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin'
```

Restart your terminal, and type `mysql`, that should get you in.

If you dont want to make the alias, try typing ``/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql into terminal. That should get MySQL running.